# Can't boot Windows 10 after Ubuntu 16.04 was installed

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, kubuntu

after installing Ubuntu 16.04, when I choose in grub startup menu to boot in Windows 10 it restart PC but loop again in grub start up menu.
I tried
- boot repair (to correct it - "recomended change")
- sudo update-grub also.
So as I wrote after installing Ubuntu 16.04, when I select Win10 in grub, it restart computer, but again shows grub bootup menu...
Basic information
- older desktop (no UEFI),
- 1. installed Win Xp, 2. Windows 10, both load without problem,
- Win10 shut down, but fast boot was not disabled (in ubuntu I can see other drives, but ubuntu cannot mount them)
- 3. installed Ubuntu 16.04

As first on HDD I had 2 NTFS partitions (50 and 70GB), on the first was Win XP, I split it ( 50GB to 20GB Win XP and new 30GB) and on new part I install win 10.
After this I split the second partition (70GB in 30GB and 40GB) and on the 30GB I install Ubuntu 16.04 (the partition during installation was split into 20GB - system and rest /shows 8,6GB/ as "HOME"), after few restart I try to choose Win 10 during booting, but as I wrote earlier, I cannot access Windows.

When you can help me, thank you for your answer/help

PS.: When I correct installation (using Win 10 installation disk) - fix MBR, I can run Win10 (including Win XP) - but of course not Ubuntu. So then I again reinstall Ubuntu 16.04, but problem occurs again, and I cannot access my Window installations...!

Comment: Have you turned Windows 10 fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Hello, as I wrote, I start install Ubuntu without disabled fast start up.

Comment: UEFI has fast boot & Windows has fast start up. Best if both are off.

Comment: Hello, Ialso noted, that it is old desktop, so no UEFI. Yet I know, that fast start up should be off, but I didn't know it before...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Refer to the instructions given on the site and your windows boot entry will be added to the grub menu.

Comment: Post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: Hello, as I wrote - Boot-repair no change, - windows boot entry is in grub menu, but when it is choosed, it repeadly show grub menu.

Comment: And here is Summary Report from Boot-Repair
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/927rmjgfrq/

Comment: You have BIOS install. And left Windows fast start up on. Note that Windows may turn fast start up on with updates. You have to boot Windows to turn fast start up off. Use Boot-Repair or your Windows repair or installer flash drive with Windows repair console and temporarily install Windows boot loader to MBR. Then fix Windows. You then can use Boot-Repair to restore grub to MBR. Grub only boots working Windows or Windows that is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk. Turn off Fast start: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Hello thank you for your help. I try to do as you wrote, it was helpful, but still when I choose to boot in Windows, after resrting PC grub loader appear again.
1. Boot fixed with Windows bootup CD (many time I start Windows 10 and XP...),
Fast start up (Win 10) disabled
2. Grub was restored with Boot-Repair
Ubuntu runs well, also drives were loaded (only this change),
but when I choosed Windows in grub menu, grub menu shows repeadly...

Boot-Repair file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vSZm7VHz58/